# Не работает форма AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

При попытке отправить форму, она отправляется как обычно, но не через AJAX. В консоле нету логов.

```
<div class="form_container">
    <div id="message"></div>
    <form id="form">
        <input type="text" name="login">
        <input type="text" name="password">
        <input type="submit" name="send" value="Отправить">
    </form>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"
        integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ=="
        crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script>
    $("#form").on("submit", function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/handler.php',
            method: 'post',
            dataType: 'html',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                $('#message').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Логично. при САБМИТЕ формы что обычно происходит?

Comment: посмотрите что такое  preventDefault. в js,

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена добавлением
event.preventDefault();

```
$("#form").on("submit", function () {
            event.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: '/handler.php',
                method: 'post',
                dataType: 'html',
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#message').html(data);
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: что-то в функции не видно аргумента в виде `event`